# Highlight with color to sql output in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have written code in PowerShell in which I am calling on SQL command xp_cmdshell 'cluster group'.

This gives the output like below.

```
output
Listing status for all available resource groups:



Group                Node            Status

-------------------- --------------- ------

Cluster Group        ldndsm05330n01  Online

Available Storage    ldndsm05330n01  Online

LDNDCM05330V05A      ldndsm05330n01  Online

LDNDCM05330V05B      ldndsm05330n01  Offline

NULL
```

I just want, whenever it comes in online it should be highlighted in green and when it's offline then it should highlighted in red.

Below is my PowerShell command.

```
function Invoke-SQL3 {
    param(
        [string] $dataSource = "$Server",
        [string] $database = "msdb",
        [string] $sqlCommand = $("xp_cmdshell 'cluster group'")
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You Could store the output of Function Invoke-SQL3 in a variable

```powershell
$output = Invoke-SQL3
```

Then you reiceve a String, a HashTable, or a list of objects (Depends the output format of the function).

In a `Foreach` statement walk all the lines or objects for the output one by one, store it in a variable, then to show Green if online, or red if offline i.e:

```powershell
if($line[$i].contains("Online")){
    Write-Host -foreground Green $line[$i]
} elseif ($line[$i].contains("Offline")) {
    Write-Host -Foreground Red $line[$i]
}
```